# Php mail function send mail to spam on gmail and aol

Tags: php, email, gmail, spam

I have used default `mail()` function to send email it sends emails to yahoo successfully but on gmail my emails are going to spam folder due a verification link, if I remove that link then goes to inbox

like is like this

`domain.com/abnd.html?code=asdjkahsjkdhkasjghdksghdkjgsakjdg`

if remove code then works, with code it goes to spam on gmail.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a number of factors:

- Maybe the actual domain name or part of the URL is affecting the overall spam score
- Is your email valid HTML and/or and have proper headers
- Does the IP address sending mail have a valid [PTR record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)
- Are there additional headers being included in the email by the server that you may not want

There are a lot of good resources and helpful things you can use from the [AOL Postmaster](http://postmaster.aol.com/Postmaster.Tech.php) site including [Technical Policy Requirements for Sending Mail to AOL.com](http://postmaster.aol.com/Postmaster.Tech.php), and the [feedback loop](http://postmaster.aol.com/Postmaster.FeedbackLoop.php).

Also see [Google Bulk Sender Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126) for more.